# How to mock a function in a imported ballerina local module in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I've created a ballerina module as below which is maintained in my local registry.

```php
import wso2/notification_grpc_client as ngc;
```

In a seperate module, In a test case I am importing the other module and trying to mock the response in one of the methods in a class in the above imported module.

```php
NotificationResponse noti = {code: "OK"};
ngc:NotificationServiceClientImpl clientMock = test:mock(ngc:NotificationServiceClientImpl);
test:prepare(clientMock).when("createApplication").thenReturn(noti);
```

but when test case is running it's getting executed without just returning mock response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by adding a function to return the mock response with `@test:Mock` configurations.

```php
@test:Mock {functionName: "createApplication", moduleName: "wso2/notification_grpc_client"}
public isolated function createApplicationMock(ApplicationGRPC createApplicationRequest, string endpoint) returns error|NotificationResponse {
    NotificationResponse noti = {code: "OK"};
    return noti;
}
```